# Graphic is sticking out into the margins

Tags: bug

On [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9267/camera-solve-error-not-showing/9270#9270) one of the pictures is sticking out into the margin on the right-hand side:

[image]

Is this because it's part of a bullet-point line that is indented?

Comment: Yep! Happens with LaTeX arrays too.